# Given $ R=\Bbb Z/8 \Bbb Z$ , find a non-constant polynomial in $R[x]$ that is a unit

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, inverse

I've been given $ R=\Bbb Z/8 \Bbb Z$ and asked to find a non-constant polynomial in $R[x]$ that is a unit.

Because units in $R[x]=$ units in $R$ and units in $R=\bar 1,\bar 3, \bar 5, \bar 7$, Would a polynomial with any of these units suffice? For example, if I let a polynomial in $ R=\Bbb Z/8 \Bbb Z$ be $f=\bar3x$, is $f$ a unit, or am I doing this wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You have $(1+4x)(1-4x)=1$ in $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: So (1+4x)(1−4x)=1 is a unit? So 3x is not a unit then?

Comment: yes, since $(1+4x)(1-4x)=1-16x^2=1$ since $16=0$ mod $8$.

Comment: in fact the unit is $1+4x$ since $(1+4x)(1-4x)=1$ mod 8.

Comment: Ohhh. That makes total sense. Would (4x-3)(4x+3)=1 also work?

Comment: Yes this works also

Comment: Of course, $1-4x=1+4x$...

Comment: $(4x-3)(4x+3)=-1$, not $1$. @eulersnumber

Comment: Oh cool thanks! It has to =1. Something that equals 1x is not a unit right?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews you're so right haha. I get excited when I'm starting to understand something and make silly mistakes

Comment: So f=(4x+1)^2 works also because (4x+1)^2=1

Comment: $(4x - 3)^2 = 16x^2 - 24x + 9 \equiv 1$ as desired. This can be deduced from the earlier observation that $(4x-3)(4x+3) = -1$ and then multiplying both sides by $-1$, since $(4x+3)(-1) = -4x-3 \equiv 4x-3$, and $(-1)(-1) = 1$.

Comment: $1$ is a unit. $(4x+1)^2=1$. $1$ is always a unit. $4x+1$ is the interesting unit. A unit is something which is a divisor of $1$.